# react-router possible to mount a component based on query param?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React, Redux, and React-Router@v2.0.0. I'm trying to figure out how to mount a top-level component when a specific query param is passed.. Is this possible?

So my existing routes look like this:

```
export default (
  <Route name="root" path="/" component={RootComponent}>
    <Route name="routeOne" path="a/route/:slug(/)" component={RouteOneComponent} />
    <Route name="routeTwo" path="a/route/:slug/:index" component={RouteTwoComponent} />
  </Route>
);
```

Now, I need to refactor `routeTwo` so that instead of being mounted at `a/route/slug/1`, it only mounts at `a/route/slug?i=1`.

is this possible? I can't seem to find anything about this in the docs. It seems that only actual routes can have a component, and the query is passed as a prop... But unfortunately this wont work for my use case. :(  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use [getComponent](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback) for this

```
<Route path="a/route/:slug" 
    getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
       if (nextState.location.query[i] === '1') {
           cb(null, RouteTwoComponent);
       } else {
           cb(null, RouteOneComponent);
       }
    }} />
```

Although I think normally one would handle such split in the render method based on props.

Comment: Thank you! This actually works great for my needs, however I'd love to hear more about the "normal" way you mentioned ( probably in my interest to follow best practices ). would you mind elaborating? I'll mark you as correct of course.